# How can I plot a list of 1's and 0's with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of 1's and 0's and I want to plot it as a series of white and black boxes (with a border). How can I accomplish this with `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array of zeros and ones can be reshaped to a 2D array and plotted as an image. Black grid lines serve as divisions between the pixels. Ticks and labels can be made invisible, if desired.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randint(0, 2, 12)
plt.imshow(x.reshape(1, -1), extent=[0, len(x), 0, 1], cmap='Greys')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(x), 1), [])
plt.yticks([])
plt.grid(True, axis='x', lw=1, c='black')
plt.tick_params(axis='x', length=0)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]